# Maintain consistent loose coupling given complex inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, dependency-injection

For the purposes of loose coupling and testing I am now replacing concrete references with interfaces and abstract classes, however I'm having trouble getting my head around the following scenario:

Say I have two concrete business layer objects whose only purpose is to call Data Access Logic methods and perform logic on the results before passing back to the controller (ASP.NET MVC 4), called `FordCar` and `CitroenCar`. They both inherit from a `Car` abstract class, which inherits from `ICar` interface:

```
public interface ICar
{
    ICarDAL DAL;
    bool StartEngine();
    bool StopEngine();
    Driver ChangeDriver(Driver d);
}

public abstract class Car : ICar
{
    private ICarDAL DAL;

    public virtual Car(ICarDAL DALInstance)
    {
        this.DAL = DALInstance;
    }

    public virtual bool StartEngine()
    {
        return this.DAL.UpdateEngine(true);
    }

    public virtual bool StopEngine()
    {
        return this.DAL.UpdateEngine(false);
    }

    public virtual Driver ChangeDriver(Driver d)
    {
        return this.DAL.UpdateDriver(d);
    }
}
```

Because the DAL contains logic that is appropriate for all cars, I implement an interface and abstract class for this too:

```
public interface ICarDAL<T>
{
    T EFContext;
    bool UpdateEngine(bool b);
    Driver UpdateDriver(Driver d);
}

public abstract class CarDAL<T> : ICarDAL<T>
{
    private T EFContext;

    public virtual bool UpdateEngine(bool b)
    {
        try
        {
            using(T db = new T())
            {
                // Perform DB update
                // return true
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle and return false
        }
    }

    // and so on..
}
```

Now say the `FordCar` has the ability to turn on windscreen heating, which the `CitroenCar` does not have. This is where I lose sight, in order to be consistent I expect I'd have to implement an additional small interfaces and abstract classes for just `FordCar` but how can I maintain using the abstract `CarDAL` class - as it holds mostly common functionality - yet call `TurnOnScreenHeating()` when it is not defined there? This requires a car type specific DAL classes, which defeats the object of my goal.

I suppose my question is: given lots of domain objects with mostly shared functionality how do I accommodate for the odd unique functionality when attempting loose coupling and dependency injection?

For in my controller I would hope to do this:

```
public class FordCarController : Controller
{
    private Car BLLMethods;

    public FordCarController()
    {
        // Init concrete type
        this.BLLMethods = new FordCar();
    }

    public ActionResult DoHeating()
    {
        this.BLLMethods.TurnOnScreenHeating();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Apologies for the convoluted scenario and poor title.

Comment: Your CarDAL<T> is an abstract class, which means you would, anyway, have to create concrete type of SomeSpecificCarDAL<T>. You cant have only abstract classes, at the end of the day we do need to instantiate something :)

Comment: That is true, I didn't include a concrete class for `FordCar` and `CitroenCar` for brevity, but the explicit car type would initialize a DAL of the appropriate type. I edited the controller code to be more clear.

Comment: I didn't mean your Car classes, i meant your DAL classes. You currently only have one abstract class called CarDal<T> which cant be instantiated, and you would still need to create a concrete type of DAL.

Comment: If you are writing a FordController specific to Ford object, I would expect you to use the Ford class rather than the Car class. 

Think about it. You are doing something specific to Ford cars and not a generic class properties.

Comment: @HamidShahid I understand, but what about testing other implementations of the `ICar` interface relating to a `FordCar`?

Comment: So any testing of ICar interface should target ICar specific functionality. From your example, lets say ICar had a method DoHeating(). Then the specific implementation of FordCar would call the TurnOnHeating method.

Lest say the bas car class has the following virtual method

public virtual void DoHeating(){ 
}

The overrided method of DoHeating in Ford would take the form

public override void DoHeating(){
  base.DoHeating();
  // Ford specific heating implmentation
}

Answer (score 4):

I have a few observations. I'm hoping one or two of them will apply to the specific situation you're running into:

1. It's often better to favor *composition over inheritance*. In other words, rather than having a `CitroenCar` and a `FordCar` that inherit from `Car`, you could just have a `Car` with a `Make` property to tell you which kind of car it is.
2. Rather than basing functionality on what you know about specific types of cars, try focusing on *feature checking*. There are a few different approaches you can take. For example:

   1. Make the objects implement feature-specific interfaces (`IHaveWindscreenHeater`).
   2. Make the main `ICar` class implement a `bool CanHeatWindscreen{get;}` property, as well as a `TurnOnScreenHeating()` method. This latter method could either do nothing or throw an exception in cars that don't have heating.
3. The fact that you're calling your controller `FordController` tells me that you can no longer loosely couple this: You're declaring it to do stuff pertaining to Ford cars, so even if you manage to decouple it from the `FordCar` class in code, you're still conceptually tightly coupled. This may be even more dangerous than having tight coupling in your code. Following observation #1 above, you may want to just use a single `CarController` class that handles all your `Car` actions.